# DataTables. How to access what is filtered and by what order in response?

Tags: datatables

I'm using DataTables in project not implemented by me, and I'm trying to figure out how to get filter and order data from Response.

In .php file that is defined in Ajax:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "../admin/ajax/product.php",
        data: function (d) {
```

... I have access to $_GET variable with data about what is filtered and what order is in use (print_r):

```
Array
(
    [draw] => 2
    [columns] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 0
                    [name] =>
                    [searchable] => false
                    [orderable] => false
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] =>
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 1
                    [name] =>
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] =>
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 5
                    [name] =>
                    [searchable] => false
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 5
                            [regex] => false
                        )

                )
        )

    [order] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [column] => 2
                    [dir] => asc
                )

        )

    [start] => 0
    [length] => 10
    [search] => Array
        (
            [value] =>
            [regex] => false
        )

    [method] => getList
)
```

Now I need these information (what is filtered and by what order) in response to do something with this data in next Request but this time without ajax and DataTable.

How to access what is filtered and by what order in response?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the datatables request parameters (ie data sent TO the server) from the response (ie data returned FROM the server)?

Comment: I asked about this https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.params() . You can answer using this link and I will accept your answer just for that You wanted help.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't really understand what you're saying. Does that link not answer your question?

Comment: this link solved my problem.